# How to iterate std::chrono::year_month_day using std::ranges::iota_view

Tags: c++, std-ranges

What I want to do is to iterate every day between two dates expressed as `std::chrono::year_month_day`, something like this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
    using std::ranges::iota_view;

    for(auto date : iota_view{1d/1/1970, 1d/1/2024})
    {
        // etc
    }
}
```

I tried also to convert the dates to `std::chrono::sys_days`, still no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map `year_month_day`s to `time_point`s to get an "iterable" type and transform the iterated `time_point` into a new `year_month_day`.

Since `time_point` currently does not meet the `weakly_incrementable` required by `iota_view`, you also need to specialize `incrementable_traits` for it to formulate an integral difference type.

```
template<class Clock, class Duration> 
struct std::incrementable_traits<std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>> { 
  using difference_type = typename Duration::rep;
};

auto make_year_month_day_range = [](std::chrono::year_month_day begin,
                                    std::chrono::year_month_day last) {
  auto begin_days = std::chrono::sys_days(begin);
  auto end_days = ++std::chrono::sys_days(last);
  return std::views::iota(begin_days, end_days)
       | std::views::transform([](auto days) { return std::chrono::year_month_day(days); });
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E6W1d9qxr)

Comment: Well done.  +1.  Contrast with: https://godbolt.org/z/qK9T54EK6